# Operators - not working dont know why?

Tags: javascript

```
{
   if (len != 6)
   alert(" Must be 6 characters long ")

   else 

    {
       if (num1 || num2 == 0)
       alert(" Please select at least 1 item ")

    else 

    {
        var totalpay = num1 * 10 + num2 * 20
        document.getElementById('total').value = totalpay;
    }

  }

}
```

When the two items are set to 1 the alert still appears as if one of them are 0, and I don't know why?

Comment: Done debugger on firefox and it doesn't see anything wrong with it?

Comment: What are you trying, what is the expected behavior and what is happening now? Your code snippet misses context.

Comment: Basically its two buy two items, and if one isn't selected the alert should appear

Comment: @Elias: Apparently the OP expects `if (num1 || num2 == 0)` to mean "if *num1* or *num2* is zero".

Comment: Yeah thats what should happen but i am selecting to buy both so both are 1 or 2 and the messae still appears?

Comment: If you know *num1* and *num2* are numbers, you can use `!num1 && !num2`, which will only be true if both *num1* and *num2* are zero.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
num1 || num2 == 0
```

you most likely wanted

```
num1 == 0 && num2 == 0
```

which corresponds with the *at least 1 item* wording.

Comment: Still not working! Its strange this code worked fine yesterday and now it doesn't?